Schedule task on Second Sunday of the month or on Third and Fourth Sunday and Saturday
I'm using C# and Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.dll to create dynamic scheduled tasks.
No problem to set a date for a specific scheduled Month date :
TaskService ts = new TaskService();
TaskDefinition tsDef = ts.NewTask();

(...)

DateTime scheduleDateTime = new DateTime(2024, 12, 31, 23, 59, 0);


m_Logger.SendMessage("Trigger Monthly...");

MonthlyTrigger objMonthlyTrigger = new MonthlyTrigger();

objMonthlyTrigger.DaysOfMonth = new int[] { scheduleDateTime.Day };
objMonthlyTrigger.StartBoundary = scheduleDateTime;
objMonthlyTrigger.EndBoundary = DateTime.MaxValue;

tsDef.Triggers.Add(objMonthlyTrigger);

My question is about to use the setting for a trigger "on a schedule Monthly" for examples :

On Second Sunday
OR
On Third and Fourth Sunday and Saturday



How can I do that ?
Thanks per advance for your help

You need MonthlyDOWTrigger. The native object is documented here, and the .NET wrapper is here.
MonthlyDOWTrigger objMonthlyTrigger = new(DaysOfTheWeek.Sunday | DaysOfTheWeek.Saturday, weeksOfMonth: WhichWeek.SecondWeek | WhichWeek.ThirdWeek)
{
    StartBoundary = scheduleDateTime,
    EndBoundary = DateTime.MaxValue,
};
tsDef.Triggers.Add(objMonthlyTrigger);


Works ! Many thanks.
